# multind.sty not found

Tags: installing, indexing

I am on a Lubuntu 15.04 pc, `texlive-full` installed. I can't compile my file with `\usepackage{multind}` because `multind.sty` is not found.

Does anyone know if it's possible to manually install this package and, if so, how?

Comment: That is a 209 package according to ctan. Besides it has no license, so is not allowed in Texlive.  See https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multind?lang=en

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By way of explanation, [multind](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multind) is a package for LaTeX 2.09 which is long deprecated (early 90s?) by the availability of LaTeX 2e.

You should take a look at modern packages for including multiple indices. [This CTAN topic](https://www.ctan.org/topic/index-multi) lists both the obsolete 2.09 package and some current ones.

- [imakeidx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/imakeidx) is popular because it avoids the need for a separate step to run the external tool which creates the index. But as [Harish Kumar points out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264230/multind-sty-not-found/264292?noredirect=1#comment634275_264292), it can also handle multiple indices.
- `index` is widely used, I think. However, the link on CTAN is broken - it has a long-standing problem with this package. Type `texdoc index` to read about it. (I guess it will be packaged in `texlive-full`.)
- [splitindex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/splitindex) is a later development which uses TeX's resources more efficiently. So you can have more than 16 indices or you can use many indices in addition to other things requiring dedicated output streams.

Comment: What about `imakeidx`? It is more powerful like its author ;)

Comment: @HarishKumar Tell that to CTAN!

Comment: @HarishKumar Thanks. I've added it. I must admit, I've only ever used it for questions on this site and I didn't realise it handled multiple indices. But I've only ever made quite simple indices and never, that I recall, more than one. (One is more than enough trouble in my experience!)